# Using a first letter to find a file or directory

Tags: keyboard, finder

I just got the most recent MacBook Air which uses Monterey MacOS, and I'd like to personalize some of the commands. On my previous MacBook, when viewing the finder as Columns, if I clicked on a file or directory and then typed a single letter, I was brought to another file or directory in the containing folder whose file name started with that letter. Now however, this only works if I select a *file*, whereas if I select a *directory*, I'm brought to a file *within* that child directory. I would like to stay searching in the parent directory, as was the case in the older MacBook Air operating system. Can I switch this back?

Thank you!
Ben